# Is it okay to ask intentionally dupe questions to help to find a real one?

Tags: discussion, search, duplicate-questions

Imagine a situation, that I've once read a question (and its answers) on a site. I would need the information again, so I try to find the question as I can (mainly, asking the search bar of the SE, and google queries with "site:X.stackexchange.com").

I can't find the question.

So, I ask intentionally the same, but this time in my formulation. I know that it will be likely closed as dupe, and from the dupe closure, I will find also the original question what I couldn't.

Of course I could also ask it ("Where is the question about...") on the meta, or on the chat. But, creating the dupe, I also make it easier for other readers in the future, to find the original question with regular search.

From the other side, asking questions intentionally for closure doesn't seem a very constructive thing.

So, which is the better option?

Comment: Duplicate closures are different from the rest, because one of the results is supposed to be to give more paths to the canonical target.

Comment: If it's basically the same wording as the target, then it's not helpful. But if you can't find the target with your current wording, I think it makes sense.

Comment: @TheWanderer If it would be basically the same wording as the target, then google or the SE search bar could have found it. Considering that the intended usage of the site is to search on it for questions with search engines, I think we can *define* "same wording" as "google/searchbar can find it with the keywords".

Comment: Also you should show your research effort so that others don’t downvote your question :)

Comment: Seeing this being dupe-closed is the irony of the day :D